# How can I have 2 independants namespace in Kubernetes without communications

Tags: kubernetes

In my K8S cluster, I have a "private" part where I have all my microservices, and a "public" part.

The public part is a blockchain, and I would like to be able to give a blockchain node to clients so that they can audit private blockchain.

Thing is right now, if I register a node within K8S, it will be able to communicate with all namespaces.

My microservices should be able to read and write in the blockchain, but the blockchain nodes should not be able to communicate with other namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [network policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to restrict communication between pods of different namespaces. So the namespaces which are for blockchain can have a label and  you can use network policy to only allow communications from pods which reside in the namespaces with that label.

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors)

`namespaceSelector`: This selects particular namespaces for which all Pods should be allowed as ingress sources or egress destinations

```
  ...
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: blockchain
  ...
```